# PHP.ini include_path on windows with different drives

Tags: php, include, require, ini

I try to include PHP file from different places of my computer. So I have defined different include paths in my php.ini

```
include_path=".;C:\project\a;X:\project\b"
```

When I try to include a file *X:\project\b\file_b.php* from a PHP script on *C:\project\a\file_a.php* with

```
require_once("file_b.php");
```

or with

```
require_once("X:\project\b\file_b.php");
```

I get the error

> Warning: require_once(X:\project\b\file_b.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\project\a\file_a.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'X:\project\b\file_b.php' (include_path='.;C:\project\a;X:\project\b') in C:\project\a\file_a.php on line 2
>
> Abort Processing during Fatal-Error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'X:\project\b\file_b.php' (include_path='.;C:\project\a;X:\project\b') Error in Script C:\project\a\file_a.php on Line 2

I have tried everything I can do with my knowlegde, but nothing works.
I hope, that someone can hlep me with solving this problem. Is there a problem with include paths on different drives on a Windows system?

Best regards,
bition

Comment: does whatever user ID your webserver is running under have the rights to access that drive/folders/file? and note that it's a good idea to NOT use backslashes for paths in php. `file_get_contents("C:\now\then\forever")` is not reading a file "forever" in the "now\then" subdirectory, it's reading `c:[linefeed]ow[tab]hen[formfeed]orever`

Comment: You can try `chdir` before the `require_once` instruction....http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

@Marc B: the files which should be included are accessible by everone. So I think there is no peermission problem with the files.

Comment: @Hackerman: chdir() ist also not working and PHP says "chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)"

Comment: Have you tried the below answer?

Comment: If you're using double quotes `"`, you need to escape backslashes with another backslash.  So, use `\\`.  The error message seems to indicate that this isn't affecting you right now, but take a look.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, I have finally the answer for my special problem.

It is really ery special, because I use BoxCryptor to encrypt my D: drive. BoxCryptor creates the virtual device X:, but it is not present for Apache and PHP. But I can configure BoxCryptor the mount the device X: as a rwal harddrive. After I set this, everythings works fine.

Sorry for the confusion about my vortual and real harddrives and thank you for your help!

Best regards,
bition

Answer (score -1):

I have found with WAMP etc in the past, that using backslashs works. Just dont encapsulate the string with double quotes "C:\path", this will process the contents as @Marc B warns. Instead encapsulate the string with single quotes 'C:\path' and then the contents are not processed.

If the backslashes in the contents of the single quote string are still being processed, try the following.

```
<?php

$path = 'X:/project/b/file_b.php';            // PATH WITH FORWARD SLASHS
$path = str_replace(chr(47) ,chr(92) ,$path); // REPLACE FORWARD WITH BACKWARD SLASHS
require_once($path);                          // RUN FILE

?>
```

Comment: The string replace is completely unnecessary.  Just use `\\ `.  Also, it shouldn't be a problem in the first place if you use single quotes.

Comment: I'm not sure thats entirely accurate, i have had issues in the past on windows systems with forward slashes in local paths. I did mention quote encapsulations in the notes before the code example.

Comment: Then don't use forward slashes... use back slashes.  The point is, you can use the backslashes in your string literal.  No need for the replacement.

Comment: Downvote my answer, and include it in your own... Seems abit unfair that... Especailly after the correct answer was given. If the two correct methods dont wory, try this... downvote :S

Comment: I downvoted your answer because what you are doing is completely unnecessary and doesn't really answer the question.  If you correct your answer, I'd happily upvote it.  And, I don't know why you think suggesting fixing quotes in a comment is somehow including your answer in mine?  I didn't even answer the question... I left a comment with the solution.

Comment: **Just dont encapsulate the string with double quotes "C:\path", this will process the contents as @Marc B warns. Instead encapsulate the string with single quotes 'C:\path' and then the contents are not processed.**

Comment: PHP will convert to OS-specific directory separators for you. So just use forward slashes for everything and let PHP do the worrying for you. The **ONLY** time you'd have to use backslashes if you're passing paths to external things, e.g. `exec('c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c blah blah blah')` - PHP doesn't process those, the OS does.

Comment: More generally you can quickly find the cause of this problem by following this checklist : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory